# Laravel4: route missingMethod when submit a form using put method(Solved, a mistake by me)

Tags: php, laravel-4

I make a form on a page like this:

`{{ Form::open(array('method'=>'put', 'url'=>URL::to('users/update').'/'.Auth::user()->id, 'class'=>'form-horizontal')) }}`

I try to update datas without go to a new page(get data) and then post on that page to update.

Then I use this route to map a method to handle request:

`Route::put('users/update/{id}', array('before'=>'csrf', 'uses'=>'UserController@updateProfile'));`

But I get contorller missing exception.

any help would be grateful :)

**Edit**

Some addition: If I use post method instead of put , I still get **missingMethod**. If I use get method at route and post method at form submission, the form data submitted will gone, then throw **tokenNotMatch** exception.

**updated**

some related code at **UserController**

```
public function updateProfile($id)
{
    if (Auth::check() && $id == Auth::user()->id) {
        /*
        if (Request::ajax()) {
            Debugbar::info('ajax');
        }*/
        $input = array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'email' => Input::get('email')
        );
        $rules = array(
            'username' => 'required|min:4|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::refresh()->with('validator', $validator->messages()->all());
        } else {
            $this->user->username = $input['username'];
            $this->user->email = $input['email'];
            $this->user->save();
            return Redirect::refresh()->with('message', Lang::get('user/message.profile_updated'));
        }
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('users/login')->with('message', Lang::get('user/message.login_first'));
    }
}
```

**Route information(Added)**

when I use `post` to submit form and set post at route, then the route information produced by Debugbar show like this:

- host           -
- uri    GET users/{_missing}
- name            -
- action    UserController@missingMethod
- before          -
- after             -

It request **GET**, why?

**Solved**

Thanks for people viewed and answered my question. And sorry, I make a mistake, In my controller, I use `Redirect::refresh()` instead of `Redirect::back()` while I am on the page requested by form. So it will request a **GET** to handle this new request after post request done.

Anyway, it make me understand more about route and something else. Not all bad things. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What it is saying is that you don't have an `updateProfile` function in your controller. Or you have a typo somewhere but it can't find that function in the UserController.

Comment: I post my updateProfile method at UserController now. Please see my updated question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that HTML forms do not support anything other than `GET` and `POST` as form methods. You can see the specifications [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method), and another Programmers StackExchange solution [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/211790).

The possible reasoning for the continued error may be caused by your `routes.php` file still using `Route::put()` instead of `Route::post()`. Your route method must match your form method if you want it to work. If you've properly changed all of this and still get an error, could you update all the information in your original post to reflect this?

Comment: when I use post, I also change route from put to post, `Route::post('users/update/{id}', array('before'=>'csrf', 'uses'=>'UserController@updateProfile'));`. And I said at __Edit__, this will produce `NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Controller method not found.`.  And about `put`, the {{ Form:open(...) }} auto generate a hidden input filed to point that this form is using put while use __post__ for method attribute of form. I think it is ok.